# Why need divide by $2$ to get number of combinations of $4$ consecutive $1$'s, in a string of $8$ bits.

Tags: combinatorics

For the case of $4$ consecutive $1$'s in a string of eight, the $14$ possible strings are:

00001111
  ,
  11110000
  ,
  01111000
  ,
  01111001
  ,
  01111010
  ,
  01111011
  ,
  00111100
  ,
  00111101
  ,
  10111100
  ,
  10111101
  ,
  00011110
  ,
  10011110
  ,
  01011110
  ,
  11011110

How to explain the same combinatorically?

Say, the four $1$'s acts a unit, hence a total of five positions are there, on which if the group is labelled G, then adjoining positions are '0' only.

_ _ _ _ _

If fix G to either end position, then 3 places have choice to have either $1,$ or $0,$ resulting in $2^3=8$ choices.

1. G _ _ _ _
  , 
 
  2. _ _ _ _ G

Then, can place G to any of the three middle positions. Each of the three such possible positions have $4$ choices.

3. _ G _ _ _
  , 
 
  4. _ _ _ G _
  , 
 
  5. _ _ G _ _

But that gives, using the combinatorics approach, the total choices as: $8+8+4+4+4= 28.$

Seems need divide by $2$ to get $14$ as answer, but cannot find justification.

Hence, request the same.

Comment: The list you've given doesn't have G0111, G0110,G0001 etc.

Comment: Your list does not include 11110001, 11110010, 11110011, 11110100, 11110101, 11110110, 11110111, or the reverse

Comment: @UmeshShankar The set of $8$ choices, for left end given to $G$ are: $G0000, G0001, G0010, G0011, G0100, G0101, G0110, G0111.$

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks, as adding the left $(2^3-1)\star 2= 14$ choices leads to a sum of $14+14=28.$

Comment: @jiten These are not there in the list you've given at the beginning. Out of 16, you've listed only 2. The 14 you seem to be missing are these.

Comment: @UmeshShankar sorry for wrong interpretation of your first comment.

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean exactly four consecutive ones or at least four consecutive ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two solutions**

$\underline{\text{Solution 1}}$

Divide into mutually exclusive cases.

Let $g(n)$ denote the number of sequences of $8$ binary strings (i.e. each character is 0 or 1), that do contain $4$ consecutive $1's$, where the **first occurrence** of the $4$ consecutive $1's$ is in position $n$, reading left to right.

Here, $n \in \{4,5,6,7,8\}.$

Then,

- $g(4) = 16$ 
  because there are $2^4$ possibilities for the characters in positions $5$ through $8$.
- $g(5) = 8$ 
  because the first $5$ characters must be $01111$, and there are $2^3$ possibilities for the $3$ remaining characters.
- $g(6) = 8$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $x01111xx$.
- $g(7) = 8$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $xx01111x$.
- $g(8) = 8$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $xxx01111$.

So, the number of satisfying strings is

$$16 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 = 48.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Solution 2}}$

Use recursion.

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of $n$ *binary* strings that do not contain $4$ consecutive 1's.

Then, the desired computation is

$$2^8 - f(8).$$

Let $f(n,k)$ denote the number of $n$ *binary* strings that do not contain $4$ consecutive 1's, where the rightmost $k+1$ characters are a $0$ followed by $k$ 1's $~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$

Then:

- $f(n) = f(n,0) + f(n,1) + f(n,2) + f(n,3).$
- $f(4,0) = 8.$
- $f(4,1) = 4.$
- $f(4,2) = 2.$
- $f(4,3) = 1.$
- $f(4) = 15.$

Further, for *large enough* values of $n$ :

- $f(n+1,0) = f(n).$
- $f(n+1,1) = f(n,0) = f(n-1).$
- $f(n+1,2) = f(n,1) = f(n-2).$
- $f(n+1,3) = f(n,2) = f(n-3).$

---

So,

- $f(5,0), f(5,1), f(5,2), f(5,3), f(5)$ equal 
  $15, 8, 4, 2, 29,~$ respectively.
- $f(6,0), f(6,1), f(6,2), f(6,3), f(6)$ equal 
  $29, 15, 8, 4, 56,~$ respectively.
- $f(7,0), f(7,1), f(7,2), f(7,3), f(7)$ equal 
  $56, 29, 15, 8, 108,~$ respectively.
- $f(8,0), f(8,1), f(8,2), f(8,3), f(8)$ equal 
  $108, 56, 29, 15, 208,~$ respectively.

So,

$$f(8) = 208$$

and the desired computation is

$$2^8 - 208 = 48.$$

---

**Addendum**

As joriki commented in response to my question, following his answer, others have interpreted the question to imply that you are not allowed to have any string of **greater** than $4$ consecutive $1$'s.

The easiest way for me to adjust my answer is by re-applying my first solution, to count the number of ways of having **at least** $5$ consecutive $1$'s.

Then, this enumeration can be deducted from my answer of $48$, which applies under the alternate interpretation that you are allowed to have more than $4$ consecutive $1$'s.

Adapting my first solution:

- $j(5) = 8$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $11111xxx$.
- $j(6) = 4$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $011111xx$.
- $j(7) = 4$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $x011111x$.
- $j(8) = 4$ 
  because the string must have form 
  $xx011111$.

So, the number of ways of having **at least** $5$ consecutive $1$'s is

$$8 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 20.$$

Therefore, the number of ways of having **exactly** $4$ consecutive $1$'s is:

$$48 - 20 = 28.$$

Comment: Request elaboration on the second solution, say the base case $f(4,0) = 8,$ as that should be the simplest to understand. Unable to understand how the value $8$ is obtained, as the length of string, $n=4,$ with the leftmost bit being $0,$ followed by zero $1$s is stated to be $8,$ rather than just $1,$ as the only string possible is: $0000.$

Comment: @jiten First, see the Addendum.  The first part of my answer (before the Addendum) was based on the interpretation that the OP (i.e. original poster) was asking for how many 8 character binary strings had $~\color{red}{\text{at least}}~ 4~$ consecutive 1's.  Both solutions 1 and 2 are based on that assumption.  Also, in solution 2, $f(n)$ is the $~\color{red}{\text{complementary}}~$ computation.  So, $f(4,0) = 8$ refers to all 4 character strings of form $xxx0.$  Here, since there are $2$ choices for each of the first three characters, $f(4,0) = 2^3.$

Comment: @jiten Consider, for example, $f(6,0), ~f(6,1), ~f(6,2), ~f(6,3).$  These functional values are represented by $xxxxx0, ~xxxx01, ~xxx011, ~xx0111.$  Here it is to be understood that (for example) $~xxxx01~$ represents all 6 character strings that do not contain 4 consecutive 1's, where $~k = 1~$ and the rightmost (1+k) digits are $0$ followed by $k$ 1's.  The idea is that $f(7,2)$, which is represented by $xxxx011$ is formed by taking $xxxx01$ and adding a $1$ on to the end of it.  Given this explanation, do you still feel that my notation is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my deleted comment, which was: "Sorry, but your definition of $f(n,k)$ seems need be changed to: "Let $f(n,k)$ ~ , where the $k+1$ characters ~". I.e., the word 'rightmost' need be removed. This correction enables me to understand $f(4,i), \, i\in \{0,1,2,3\}.$" Have no doubt left, except to modify your second approach to my question, of 'exactly' $4$ ones. To that you seem to provide inputs, in your first comment, though not clear.

Comment: @jiten As for your *actual* question of "exactly" 4 ones, I question whether recursion is a good approach to attacking this.  Of course, you could parallel my Addendum by using recursion to determine the **complement** to the number of sequences of **at least** 5 consecutive 1's, and then take the difference.  This would be very similar to what I did in the Addendum.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't $f(5,0)=2^4,$ given by the possible combinations $xxxx0,$ where $x\in \{0,1\},$ leading to: $00000, 00010, 000100, 000110,\cdots, 11110;$ hence $f(n+1,0)= f(n)+1?$

Comment: @jiten No, $~f(n,k)~$ is the number of binary strings of length $~n~$ that do not contain any string of $4$ consecutive 1's, and that have the rightmost digits be $~0,~$ followed by $~k~$ 1's.  So, $~f(4) = 15,~$ which represents that there are $15$ strings of length $~4~$ that do not have $~4~$ consecutive 1's.  Therefore, the number of strings of length $~5~$ that do not have $4$ consecutive 1's, and have the rightmost digit equal to $~0~$ must be $~15.~$  That is, such a string can only be formed by taking any satisfying string of length $~4~$ and adding a $~0~$ to the right of it.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, the initial list of $14$ strings was missing $14$ of the $16$ strings that start or end with four consecutive $1$s.

Comment: I got that there are $48$ satisfying strings.  See my answer.  Did I misinterpret the problem or make an analytical mistake?

Comment: @user2661923: I (and apparently the other commenters) took the question to imply that the string should have *exactly* $4$ consecutive $1$s, not more. Although this is not stated explicitly, it seems to be implied in both enumerations in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I will edit my answer accordingly.